# How to copy error message in Android Studio tooltip

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

How can you select or copy the error tooltips that appear when hovering over code in Android Studio?

For example:
[image: Tooltip Error Android Studio]

Is there a key command? I'm on Mac if that's relevant.
Thanks!

Comment: @paulo-mattos this question is **NOT** about `java` and tag `java` is **NOT** proper.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Okay, no worries. But `keyboard-shortcuts` should definitely be in there as well ;-)

Comment: Questionable. It's not about keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Actually [tag:keyboard-shortcuts] should really be in there... Good spot Paulo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac, a slightly different dance than Windows.

- hold <kbd>shift</kbd>
- click **and hold** towards the end of the text(probably missing last character)
- keep holding mouse click and release <kbd>shift</kbd>
- while holding mouse click, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy
- paste wherever

Comment: @PauloMattos, I presume so though I don't have it installed. Have never thought about this before I saw the question and just worked it out through trying a few things...

Answer (score 12):

On Windows: try,

1. Hover over the yellow popup text
2. Alt+LeftMouseClick
3. The 'yellow text' should now be on your clipboard, ready to paste.

That is it!

Answer (score 6):

The older solutions don't seem to be working for me.  Not sure if the behavior changed, but here is what is working for me on a Mac with Android Studio 3.4:

1. press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> simultaneously
2. hover over the text that has an error
3. click on the tooltip when it pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu:

When you make the popup shows up, hold Alt+Shift and carefully select any amount of the text and press Ctrl+C.

You don't need to select all of the text, because it will always copy the whole message ignoring the selection.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Android Studio 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Once popup shows up, move your mouse pointer over it and simply **select** (mark) bubble's text, then do `Copy` with keyboard shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Mac) while still having mouse pointer over the bubble.

Not sure how on Mac, but on Windows it works that way for me, with the exception that you need to keep mouse pointer over the bubble all the time otherwise it is gone (which sometimes forces me to copy all but last character from that message).

Comment: Thanks Marcin :) I did try that but as Lewis answered above, you need to hold down shift (on Mac) or the tooltip disappears when you click it...

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, try

1. Hover on the error or warning popup text
2. Maintain CTRL to keep it displayed
3. Use the cursor to select the text