# How to copy the wrong hint when I use Android Studio 3.01?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I use Android Studio 3.01, it will display the wrong hint "Expecting member declaration" when there are some problem with my code.

But the text information of the wrong hint is hard to copy, it will be disappear immediately if the mouse is out of the hint area. I hardly to select the text of hint and click Copy item from Right-click menu.

Is there a simple way to do it? such as keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

**Add Content**

Many times that both the error hint and keyword hint are displayed simultaneously!

[image]

Comment: Exactly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664924/how-to-copy-error-message-in-android-studio-tooltip

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look to this question :
[How to copy error message in Android Studio tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664924/how-to-copy-error-message-in-android-studio-tooltip)
which contain the answer:

> Once popup shows up, move your mouse pointer over it and simply select (mark) bubble's text, then do Copy with keyboard shortcut (CTRL+C on Windows or Command+C on Mac) while still having mouse pointer over the bubble.

Comment: Would you please see my modified question?

Many times that both the error hint and keyword hint are displayed simultaneously,
it's hard to move mouse to the area of  error hint, and many time the error hint will disappear when I try to select text of error hint i Windows OS.